# Rails Dev Server not visible on network

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to do something very basic and test my Rails app on my phone.

Starting the server with:

```
rails s
```

But when accessing `mymachinename.local:3000`, Mobile Safari says that the server stopped responding after about 30 seconds.

I do this all the time on other machines, but I have no idea what could be causing it here. Any suggestions?

Comment: `localhost:3000` would cause the phone to look to itself, I'm trying to connect to the dev server on a machine on the same network.

Comment: My bad. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Have you checked that the firewall is allowing the connection?

Comment: Gah! @sosborn No duh. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops. Firewall. Don't know why I even had it turned on.

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar issue before trying to access the server from a virtual machine, I had to use the following format for the rails server command:
`rails s -b your.dev.ip.address`